# How to fill a column by group with sampled row numbers according to n per group

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with a dataframe in `R`. I have groups stated by column `Group1`. I need to create a new column named `sampled` where I need to fill with a specific value after using `sample` per group from 1 to each number of rows per group. Here is the data I have:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
dat <- data.frame(Group1=sample(letters[1:3],15,replace = T))
```

Then `dat` looks like this:

```
dat
   Group1
1       b
2       a
3       a
4       c
5       c
6       c
7       a
8       b
9       c
10      b
11      a
12      b
13      c
14      c
15      c
```

In order to get the `N` per group, we do this:

```
#Code
dat %>% 
  arrange(Group1) %>%
  group_by(Group1) %>%
  mutate(N=n())
```

Which produces:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 2
# Groups:   Group1 [3]
   Group1     N
   <chr>  <int>
 1 a          4
 2 a          4
 3 a          4
 4 a          4
 5 b          4
 6 b          4
 7 b          4
 8 b          4
 9 c          7
10 c          7
11 c          7
12 c          7
13 c          7
14 c          7
15 c          7
```

What I need to do is next. I have the `N` per group, so I have to create a sample of 3 numbers from `1:N`. In the case of group `a` having `N=4` it would be `sample(1:4,3)` which produces `[1] 2 4 3`. With this in the group `a` I need that rows belonging to sampled values must be filled with `999`. So for first group we would have:

```
   Group1     N sampled
   <chr>  <int>   <int>
 1 a          4    NA
 2 a          4    999
 3 a          4    999
 4 a          4    999
```

And then the same for the rest of groups. In this way using `sample` we will have random values per group. Is that possible to do using `dplyr` or `tidyverse`. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
set.seed(3242)

library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  arrange(Group1) %>%
  add_count(Group1, name = 'N') %>%
  group_by(Group1) %>%
  mutate(
    sampled = case_when(
      row_number() %in% sample(1:n(), 3L) ~ 999L,
      TRUE ~ NA_integer_
    )
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 15 × 3
# Groups:   Group1 [3]
   Group1     N sampled
   <chr>  <int>   <int>
 1 a          4     999
 2 a          4     999
 3 a          4      NA
 4 a          4     999
 5 b          4     999
 6 b          4     999
 7 b          4     999
 8 b          4      NA
 9 c          7      NA
10 c          7     999
11 c          7      NA
12 c          7     999
13 c          7      NA
14 c          7      NA
15 c          7     999
```